# Литература по нейросетям

Tags: алгоритм, c++, нейронные-сети

Всем привет. Не подскажите литературу по нейронным сетям? Только не по теории,а именно по их реализации на языке программирования. Желательно C++. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужна именно литература? Не уверен, что есть книжки по нейронным сетям, где используется именно C++.
Но зато в интернете при желании можно найти множество примеров реализации нейронно-сетевых алгоритмов с исходниками. Наверняка, некоторые из них даже содержат нормальные комментарии содержат :)

Например:

http://www.ishodniki.ru/list/alg/alg-neiron/neiron_net/ (статьи по нейронными сетям с примерами на плюсах)

http://www.orc.ru/~stasson/neurox.html (статьи по нейронными сетям с примерами на плюсах)

http://alglib.sources.ru/#download (мощная библиотека численного анализа с открытым кодом, содержащая в том числе и нейро-сетевые методы)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, гугл в помощь... Но если ничего не находится... Посмотрите [тут](http://www.orc.ru/~stasson/neurox.html), вот [эту программу](http://netcode.ru/cpp/?lang=&katID=9&skatID=105&artID=3994)....

Comment: Собственно, первая ссылка приведена выше)